# Intellij Idea Language injection for string - error 'class' or 'interface' expected

Tags: java

I want add syntax highlight to string. I do next.

```
@Language("Java")
String text = "x != null";
```

But IntelliJ Idea highlight string error underline and write.
'class' or 'interface' expected. How I can to improve this?

Comment: is this the full code? or just a part of it

Comment: The error is pretty explicit. A field must be in a class, hence it's **expecting you to declare a class**. There's no such thing as a global variable in Java, if that's what you're trying to define.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inject a language in IntelliJ, you must follow the rules of that language.
Obviously in Java you cannot have such a statement in isolation, instead it must be contained inside a class or a method, as property / local variable / control block.

```
@Language("Java")
final String test = "class Test { "
        + "   private final String myProp = \"It works!\";"
        + ""
        + "   public void myMethod() {"
        + "      boolean i = false;"
        + "      "
        + "      if (i) {"
        + "        /* My comment */"
        + "      }"
        + "   }"
        + "}";
```

Comment: Ok I understand. But when I want to do next:   @Checker("x != null") private String x;    I want only highlight syntax java in parameter string annotation. How I can to do?

Comment: @KotLeapold unfortunately you cannot. But feel free to ask JetBrains via YouTrack. They're friendly

Comment: Thanks. I understand.